# Why does autoincrement change value on failed request? How i can fix it?

Tags: postgresql, orm, fastapi

I have table in database with columns

```
some_table = Table(
    "some_table",
    metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True),
    Column("Courier_id", Integer, ForeignKey("courier.id")),
    Column("Order_id", Integer, ForeignKey("order.id"), index=True, unique=True),
    Column("Time", String),
    Column("Status", String)
)
```

And i need use order id only once, so this column is unique.
So, for example, i make a request to insert with values `(courier_id=1, order_id=1, time="time", status="status")` and i get the values in my table

```
id | courier_id | order_id | time | status
1  | 1          | 1        | time | status
```

I do it next time with the same values ang get mistake because order_id is unique(it's okay), but when i insert new values for example `(courier_id=2, order_id=2, time="time", status="status")` and i get in my table

```
id | courier_id | order_id | time | status
1  | 1          | 1        | time | status
5  | 2          | 2        | time | status
```

And now it's not okay. I tried to use Sequence(Serial) and Identity, buy it was the same.
My function in python

```
async def add_confirm_order(new_order: RequestConfirmOrderCreate, session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_async_session)):
    try:
        stmt = insert(confirm_order).values(**new_order.dict())
        await session.execute(stmt)
        await session.flush()
    except Exception:
        await session.rollback()
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400)
    finally:
        await session.close()
    await session.commit()
```

So, why does autoincrement work like this and how to fix it?

Comment: That’s how a sequence works and there is nothing you can, nor want, to change it. If you need numbers without gaps, don’t you autoincrement. Lock your tables, destroy performance, get the last number, create a new record and unlock the tables. In rare occasions you need this, most of the time you don’t want it nor need it

Comment: But how does it work if it doesn't add anything to the table? Before I encountered this problem, I thought that nothing happens when an error occurs

Comment: A sequence doesn’t roll back, check the manual

Comment: And to build on what @FrankHeikens is saying, when you have an `id` column, it should just be a unique identifier, nothing else. You should not rely on your `id`s to be in a certain order, and you should never expose them to systems not directly in contact with the database (so they should never appear in URLs or be shown to end users).

Comment: Read the docs [Create Sequence](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/7.1/database_dialog.html) in paricular the **Notes** section.

Comment: This is normal and as it should be. See [my article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/gaps-in-sequences-postgresql/) for details.